# jQuery replace and add new string when click

Tags: jquery, replace, html-table, click

I have a small form that has number and name on it. It shows `number_name` when you click button. For example, if you click button, it will popup `1,2_Tod`, my question is... how to replace comma to underline between the number, so the number part will looks like `1_2` instead of `1,2`, and add `_ordered` after the name part, so the name part will looks like `Tod_ordered`, and the whole string will looks like `1_2_Tod_ordered`. And I have another question, is it possible to swap string when click button to make `1_2_Tod_ordered` looks like `Tod_ordered_1_2`?

```js
$('.button').click(function(){
    var data = $('.number,.name').map(function () {
  return $(this).text();
 }).get().join('_');
 
    alert(data);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="dataTable">
    <tr id="data1">
        <td class="number">1,2</td>
        <td class="name">Tod</td>
    </tr>
     <tr id="data2">
        <td class="number">8,10</td>
        <td class="name">Smith</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<button type="button" class="button">Order</button>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x4zavtdp/3/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For getting data like: 1_2_Tod_ordered_8_10_Smith_ordered

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sanno_s88/x4zavtdp/5/)

```
$('.button').click(function(){
    var data1 = $('.number,.name').map(function () {
        var text = $(this).text();
        if($(this).hasClass('name')) {
            text += '_ordered';
        } else if($(this).hasClass('number')) {
            text = text.replace(/,/g, "_");
        }
        return text;
    }).get().join('_');

    alert(data1);
    console.log(data1);
});

<table id="dataTable">
    <tr id="data1">
        <td class="number">1,2</td>
        <td class="name">Tod</td>
    </tr>
     <tr id="data2">
        <td class="number">8,10</td>
        <td class="name">Smith</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<button type="button" class="button">Order</button>
```

---

### Update

This has both the options:

1_2_Tod_ordered_8_10_Smith_ordered

Tod_ordered_1_2_Smith_ordered_8_10

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sanno_s88/x4zavtdp/7/)